# Run Node JS on a multi-core cluster cloud

Tags: node.js, parallel-processing, cluster-computing, aws-lambda

Is there a service or framework or any way that would allow me to run Node JS for heavy computations letting me choose the number of cores?

I'll be more specific: let's say I want to run some expensive computation for each of my users and I have 20000 users.
So I want to run the expensive computation for each user on a separate thread/core/computer, so I can finish the computation for all users faster.

But I don't want to deal with low level server configuration, all I'm looking for is something similar to [AWS Lambda](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/) but for high performance computing, i.e., letting me scale as I please (maybe I want 1000 cores).

I did simulate this with AWS Lambda by having a "master" lambda that receives the data for all 20000 users and then calls a "computation" lambda for each user. Problem is, with AWS Lambda I can't make 20000 requests and wait for their callbacks at the same time (I get a request limit exceeded error).

With some setup I could user [Amazon HPC](https://aws.amazon.com/hpc/), [Google Compute Engine](https://cloud.google.com/compute/) or [Azure](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/scenarios/high-performance-computing/), but they only go up to 64 cores, so if I need more than that, I'd still have to setup all the machines I need separately and orchestrate the communication between them with something like [Open MPI](https://www.open-mpi.org/), handling the different low level setups for master and compute instances (accessing via ssh and etc).

So is there any service I can just paste my Node JS code, maybe choose the number of cores and run (not having to care about OS, or how many computers there are in my cluster)?

I'm looking for something that can take that code:

```
var users = [...];

function expensiveCalculation(user) {
    // ...
    return ...;
}

users.forEach(function(user) {
    Thread.create(function() {
        save(user.id, expensiveCalculation(user));
    });
});
```

And run each thread on a separate core so they can run simultaneously (therefore finishing faster).

Comment: Are you looking for something that automatically manages multiple processes on multiple servers to give you 1000 cores?  Do you have servers just sitting idle waiting for this or are you also looking for something that uses one of the pre-built dynamic resource engines that will spin up resources as needed (like on AWS)?

Comment: FYI, asking for a 3rd party tool that accomplishes some task is considered "off-topic" here on StackOverflow.  Asking how to code it yourself (after appropriate research and your own attempts) is considered "on-topic".

Comment: @jfriend00 second one =), something that will manage itself like AWS Lambda, but if that is not an option, I can turn on my 1000 cores, do my processing and turn off when I'm done.

Comment: Well, I'll accept any answer that satisfy my needs, it could be some code that solves it, like my attempt with AWS Lambda.

Comment: What you may want is AWS Spot instances and some queue management.

Comment: I think those are just like regular instances, but cheaper. I'll still have to configure what to run on each one separately.

Comment: The **request limit exceeded(429)** error you are seeing when using AWS Lambda is most likely due to the default safety limit of 100 concurrent executions within a given region. You can have this limit increased to what you require by submitting a limit increase for concurrent executions. This is explained in more detail [here.](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/concurrent-executions.html#concurrent-execution-safety-limit).

Comment: Thank you, that's actually very helpful! Is there a way to increase the computation power of each lambda? And do you think AWS Lambda would be appropriate for my type of problem then?

Comment: [AWS Lambda FAQs](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/faqs/#functions)
_Q: How are compute resources assigned to an AWS Lambda function?

In the AWS Lambda resource model, you choose the amount of memory you want for your function, and are allocated proportional CPU power and other resources. For example, choosing 256MB of memory allocates approximately twice as much CPU power to your Lambda function as requesting 128MB of memory and half as much CPU power as choosing 512MB of memory. You can set your memory in 64MB increments from 128MB to 1.5GB._

Comment: The answer to your second question will depend on your use case. I would process a batch with Lambda, process a batch with alternative solutions and make a decision from the results, considering cost, execution time and any other factors relevant to your use case. Lambda should simplify meeting you requirement of "finish the computation for all users faster" but you need to consider all factors relevant to your use case.

Comment: So if I choose 1024 MB, I'd have 16 cores? Or the raw speed increases? or Both?

Answer (score 1):

I think that your problem is that you feel the need to process 20000 inputs at once on the same machine. Have you looked into SQS from Amazon? Maybe you push those 20000 inputs into SQS and then have a cluster of servers pull from that queue and process each one individually.

With this approach you could add as many servers, processes or add as many AWS Lambda invokes as you want. You could even use a combination of the 3 to see what's cheaper or faster. Adding resources will only reduce the amount of time it would take to complete the computations. Then you wouldn't have to wait for 20000 requests or anything to complete. The process could tell you when it completes the computation by sending some notification after it completes.

So basically, you could have a simple application that just grabbed 10 of these inputs at a time and ran your computation on them. After it finishes you could then have this process delete them from SQS and send a notification somewhere (Maybe SNS?) to notify the user or some other system that they are done. Then it would repeat the process.

After that you could scale the process horizontally and you wouldn't need a super computer in order to process this. So you could either get a cluster of EC2 instances that ran several of these applications a piece or have a Lambda function invoked periodically in order to pull items out of SQS and process them.

**EDIT:**

To get started using an EC2 instance I would look at the docs [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/EC2_GetStarted.html). To start with I would pick the smallest, cheapest instance (T2.micro I think), and leave everything at it's default. There's no need to open any port other than the one for SSH.

Once it's setup and you login, the first thing you need to do is run `aws configure` to setup your profile that way you can access AWS resources from the instance. After that install Node and get your application on there using git or something. Once it's setup though, go to the EC2 console and in your Actions menu there will be an option to create an image from the instance.

Once you create an image, then you can go to Auto Scaling groups and create a launch configuration using that AMI. Then it'll let you specify how many instances you want to run.

I feel like this could also be done more easily using their container service, but honestly I don't know how to use it yet.

Comment: How do I setup this cluster of servers without having to manually setup low level configurations for each instance? (by not using low level I mean no ssh and not me manually installing NodeJS on each computer, for example)

Comment: AWS Lambda would work, but it's not meant for raw processing power, therefore it's expensive for this kind of stuff.

Comment: Well you wouldn't have to do it any more than once. And all you would have to do is setup one EC2 instance and make a AMI or copy of it. Plus, for Lambda it could be expensive, but they give you generous amount of free usage that lasts past the first year. Honestly though, I'd be surprised if you are able to accomplish this without it being a little expensive. When it comes done to it, computing stuff costs money and it sounds like you need to do a ton of it.

Comment: I guess you're right. Do you know any tutorials that can teach me how to setup the EC2 instance? the ones I found explain how to run a specific software, not how to install NodeJS and run JavaScript code.